# Blank SIM ICC ID in Mobile Broadband Hardware information on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mobile-broadband, sim

I recently added a Sierra Wireless mobile broadband card to my Dell Latitude E6330. In order to activate service, I need both the IMEI and the SIM ICC ID. When I look at the information in PC settings -> Wireless -> Mobile Broadband Hardware, I see the IMEI, but the SIM ICC ID is blank. This is a new Windows 8 Pro operating system installation. What can I do to get the SIM ICC ID?

[image: Mobile Broadband on Windows 8 Pro]

I installed this [Dell Wireless 5808e/5808 driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=jp75t), which replaced "Mobile broadband" with "Mobile broadband 2" and added a "GPS" device to the list. However, the SIM ICC ID is still missing:

[image: After installing update]

For reference, this is what my card looks like. This is not my card, but the exact model (the photos are from [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/p/0EP-004M-001A6?item=9SIA9AX7HP1885&ignorebbr=1&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googlemkp-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googlemkp-pc-_-pla-splus%20technologies-_-network%20-%20wireless%20adapters-_-9SIA9AX7HP1885&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIyOqAp9C04wIVUZ7ACh2P3QLbEAQYASABEgK41_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)). My card differs only in the IMEI, the MEID, and code at the bottom (including bar codes and QR code):

[image: DW5808 (front)]

[image: DW5808 (back)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this modem, a separate SIM card is required. I was thrown off by the Windows 8.0 user interface, because it didn't indicate that the SIM card was missing.

However, after upgrading to Windows 8.1, I was immediately notified of this problem:

[image: Windows 8.1 prompt for SIM]

The SIM card slot for this laptop is inside the battery compartment:

[image: SIM card slot on Dell E6330]

After inserting and activating a SIM card:

[image: After adding/activating SIM card]

Comment: Take a look at https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e6330_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf#page=13 -- it says the laptop has a SIM card slot under the battery. (I'm not sure if it can communicate with any 4G modem or only with the Dell-approved ones though.)

Comment: @grawity Thank you for the advice! I was able to get broadband working with a SIM card from AT&T. It turns out that their mobile hotspots all use Sierra Wireless modems, so it was pretty straightforward to activate it on that network. I had also tried it with Cricket Wireless (which uses AT&T's network) but their system refused to accept the IMEI on this modem.

Answer (score 1):

#### What can I do to get the SIM ICC ID?

Look at the SIM Card:

> ICCIDs are stored in the SIM cards and are also engraved or printed on the SIM card body during a process called personalisation. The number is up to 22 digits long, including a single check digit. Each ICCID is starting with and Issuer Identification Number (IIN).

Source [EMnify 8988303 ICCID, IIN and SIM Serial Number Explained](https://www.emnify.com/blog/2016/05/06/emnify-8988303-iccid-iin-and-sim-serial-number-explained)

Examples :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the information, but my card doesn't have these. I've added photos of the front and back to my question.

Comment: @vallismortis Have you checked the packaging for any documentation?

Comment: @vallismortis: Those photos are of the 4G modem, not of the SIM card. Do you know for sure that your modem is supposed to have a SIM card "built in"? I've never heard of that being done, except maybe for Apple's eSIM stuff.

Comment: @grawity Holy cow, thank you, I'm new to WWAN - I thought the SIM card was built in to the device, now I need to double-check.